# Orthogonal diagonalization of a special symmetric matrix with constant diagonal entries

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices, orthogonal-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

I have a real $n\times n$ symmetric matrix of the form $(A)_{ij}=\varphi^{\vert i-j\vert}$, for example for $n=3$:
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1&\varphi&\varphi^2\\
\varphi&1&\varphi\\
\varphi^2&\varphi&1
\end{pmatrix}, \qquad\varphi\in\mathbb R.
$$

Is there a simpler way, compared to a generic symmetric matrix, to find the orthogonal diagonalization $A=O^tDO$?

Extra question: do matrices of this form have a name?

Comment: This kind of matrix is a [Toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix). If you look under "General properties", I believe that the trick for positive semidefinite Toeplitz matrices will apply whenever $|\varphi| \leq 1$.

Comment: Toeplitz matrices are more general, each diagonal can have an arbitrary value. The unitary diagonalization there reduces to solving a system of equations $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \alpha_k^m d_k=\varphi^{\vert m\vert}$ for $\alpha_k$ in the unit circle, $d_k$ real and $m=0,\ldots,n-1$. I can't get any further from there.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Moreover, Vandermonde matrices are not orthogonal or unitary, even in this special case.

Comment: Some good answers at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68099/diagonalizing-a-certain-real-and-symmetric-toeplitz-matrix
In summary, no explicit diagonalization is known, but one can compute some spectral properties.